# How to structure a web scraper project?

Tags: python, wordpress, beautifulsoup, architecture, content-management-system

I have a project that is to collect posts from several second hand vehicle websites using BeautifulSoup and then store them in a database. Also my client requested to build this functionality on top of some content management system he is familiar or semi-familiar with like wordpress.

Can this be done using wordpress without making a big mess out of it? If not how would you suggest to structure my project and what cms to use?

Comment: You can use WordPress to store the data as a custom post type of "Second Hand Vehicle", add all the data, and then search like you'd search any other custom post type.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress seems to support only **mySQL** and **MariaDB**, according to their site: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases. Those seem to be your only database-tech options if you want to maintain Wordpress support.

From there, it's up to whatever is easier for your python to access, to be honest.